# facebook access_token problem

Tags: php, facebook

I just wrote a little application(4 page php), everything work fine, however, I have a question that, do I need to create a new instance of facebook (just like $facebook = new facebook.....) in every new php page, or just pass a access token or session? If only pass the access token, how can I use the function $faceook->api('something'); to acheive the data?

Because I'm a beginner of php, I have no idea how access token work, please help, thanks a lot!

Regards,

YK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file like `config.php` with new facebook instance code:

```
$facebook = new facebook.......
```

And include that file in your files where you may need to use API functions.